Foreground service permissions Google Play Console
I want to upload a new APK to Google Play Console. I updated to Android 14, and now I am using two new permission:
FOREGROUND_SERVICE_HEALTH 
FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION

But Google Play Console now requires to demonstrate how I am using these permissions and upload a video. What exactly should I show in that video and where to upload it in order to provide a link to it?


I am trying to add a foreground service permission in the google play console, can you tell me how to navigate to this page? Many thans

I put an unlisted video on youtube and provided google with the URL. The video should demonstrate whatever it is that your app needs the permission for.
I talked throughout my video explaining what was happening.
I'll tell you this in secret: my app was approved and I can see that my video has 0 views. Google never even looked at it.

I think they do. They refused my videos 5 times. I'm still trying by now. No idea what exactly they need.
